# how to extract all next page data by selenium scrapy webdriver in python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from selenium import webdriver

class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "len"
    allowed_domains = ["support.lenovo.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://support.lenovo.com/in/hi/contactus1/findaprovider/service-provider-list?countrycode=in"]

def parse(self, response):
    for sel in 
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get(self.start_urls)
    d1 = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
    html = str(d1)
    response = TextResponse('none',200,{},html,[],None)
    url = driver.current_url

    elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("page-next")
    elem.click()
    self.fun(url)

def fun(url): #function to extract data on each page
```

Im trying to extract all the 50 pages details.. Ive code to extract one page data by using scrapy but i want to extract all 50 pages. I know this can be done by using selenium..
can anyone tell me the logic or reply me some examples with so that i can understand how to extract data from all pages..

this is the link.. https://support.lenovo.com/in/hi/contactus1/findaprovider/service-provider-list?countrycode=in

Comment: use for loop before using this code and it will run for 50 times .. if your links are dynamic like changing you can specify them in an array and you can use it with the loop as for first execution first link for second execution second link and likewise you can achieve the functionality

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use Selenium, you can access the data from this link, without javascript:

https://support.lenovo.com/services/in/hi/serviceproviderlist/getlist/7c0c7e28-bfe3-475a-92af-1ab7bb055515?dataSource=a16fe443-173c-43b7-b5b6-1d86adb8774a&selectedCountry=in&bySortOrder=Ascending&BySortField=State&pageNumber=1

And just increment the page number:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
from selenium import webdriver

class Spider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "len"
    allowed_domains = ["support.lenovo.com"]

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    for i in range(50):
      self.start_urls.append('https://support.lenovo.com/services/in/hi/serviceproviderlist/getlist/7c0c7e28-bfe3-475a-92af-1ab7bb055515?dataSource=a16fe443-173c-43b7-b5b6-1d86adb8774a&selectedCountry=in&bySortOrder=Ascending&BySortField=State&pageNumber='+str(i))

def parse(self, response):
    ***your scrapy code***
```

Comment: thank u.. this is simple ..